# Can't unzip owncloud

Tags: unzip

I wanted to download owncloud to my ubuntu server, but it can't unzip it, it doesn't recognize my file, and then the file is there, but it doesn't recognize it. I tried to delete it and download it again, but it didn't work.

I downloaded it from  `cd /tmp $ wget download.owncloud.org/community/owncloud-10.0.3.zip` to tmp and than unzipped it. When i tried to use the command `unzip` I got an error code: cannot find zipfile directory in one of owncloud-10.0.3.zip.

Comment: Please give us details... the exact steps you're trying to do with.

Comment: hy i just want to unzip owncloud, i dowlod it from $ cd /tmp 
$ wget https://download.owncloud.org/community/owncloud-10.0.3.zip to tmp and than unzip when i tryd to use the comman unzip i get a erroe code :cannot fiind zipflie directoy in one of onwcloud-10.0.3.zip

Comment: also i follow this huide if ith help s help https://hostadvice.com/how-to/web-hosting/ubuntu/how-to-install-own-cloud-on-ubuntu-18-04-serve/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The guide you're following has errors in it.

The file you are trying to download doesn't exist. If you blindly run the wget command you'll get redirected to [this page](https://download.owncloud.com/), which is html, not a zip file.

You probably want [this file](https://download.owncloud.com/server/owncloud-10.11.0.zip) instead.

Comment: hi, could you help me upload this file to my ubuntu server, i'm quite new to here